# Fillng in excel cells automatically using data

Tags: excel

I am wondering if and how this can be done:

I have a spreadsheet that has three columns for Highschool name, State and CEEB code.

As of now, we have to manually look up the CEEB code and fill them in.

Is there a way i can give excel the entire list of all HSs and CEEB codes, so when I enter a High School and hit tab, it fills in the CEEB code automatically if it exists in the list provided to excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a separate sheet, list the highschools and CEEBs.  If you put the high school name in A1, put this formula in B1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B100,2,FALSE)
```

with your high schools and CEEBs on Sheet2 and in the range A1:B100.  Adjust to fit your actual data.  If you don't have anything in A1 and don't want to see an error, use this formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A1:B100,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: thanks a ton...with some minor adjustments, that works like a charm